# SVN post commit stucks while starting process

Tags: svn, visualsvn, post-commit

I've built a script in VS that receives the 2 arguments sent by post-commit hook.

The script runs SVN LOG to retrieve data about the revision (author, date, files).

When I run the solution from VS with constant vars for the arguments, it runs perfectly.

When I execute the exe file, also runs perfectly.

When I implement the hook script, it fails where it should read from the process.

```
process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            str = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();

            if (!process.HasExited)
            {

                try
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }
                catch (Exception e3)
                {

                    // process is terminated
                }

                // Write Errors

            }
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
The commit window stucks and never completes the commit.
I write the code in C#.... there is no errors shown...